# Todolist Cordova Application

Tags: cordova

I have developed two different cordova projects. One is todolist to add and delete task and another to set reminder. I want to make an app that has two tabs one running todolist project and another running reminder project. Please tell how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways

1. You can write a lot of html and css code manually to create two tabs, which will be very tedious and take time
2. You can use open source mobile UI. They will provide you provide you support all these custom UI features.

Each UI framework is supported by different javascript frameworks and library. You need to choose according your suitability.

Some Notable UI Frameworks:

- [JQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/)
- [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/)
- [Mobile Angular UI](http://mobileangularui.com/)
- [Sencha Touch](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/)
- [Framework 7](http://framework7.io/)

There are several other frameworks, which you can find after a little bit search

Answer (score 0):

[Syncfusion Orubase](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/orubase) complements PhoneGap/Apache Cordova by providing HTML/JS libraries and .NET server side libraries. There is a [Tab control](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/mobile/#tab) included.

You will find samples to get started.

[image: Orubase]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.